# Duplicate substring removal from list

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe

I have a dataframe with a product_type column that has duplicate substrings within strings:

#### df1

```
product_type
bag,bag
tote bag,bag

handbag,handbag
```

I'm using this line to remove to create a new column "unique_type" the duplicate substrings

```
df_1['unique_type'] = [set(sub.split(',')) for sub in df_1["product_type"]]
```

This is what the new dataframe looks like

#### current output

```
product_type         unique_type
bag,bag              {'bag'}
tote bag, bag        {'tote bag', 'bag'}
                     {''}
handbag, handbag     {'handbag'}
```

The problem is that the strings in the new column unique_type has curly brackets and quotation marks. I would like to produce a column that has strings without curly brackets and quotation marks like so:

#### desired output

```
product_type         unique_type
bag,bag              bag
tote bag, bag        tote bag, bag
                 
handbag, handbag     handbag
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `join`:

```
df_1['unique_type'] = [', '.join(set(sub.split(','))) for sub in df_1["product_type"]]
```

Or if need same order of values use `dict.fromkeys` trick:

```
df_1['unique_type1'] = [', '.join(dict.fromkeys(sub.split(',')))
                                                     for sub in df_1["product_type"]]


print (df_1)
      product_type    unique_type   unique_type1
0          bag,bag            bag            bag
1     tote bag,bag  bag, tote bag  tote bag, bag
2                                               
3  handbag,handbag        handbag        handbag
```